# iPhone中のイメージをリネームするには

Tags: swift, iphone

いつもお世話になります。
iPhone で撮った写真をリネームする方法はいくらでもありますが、swiftを使ってiPhone中の写真を直接リネームする方法を模索しています。
簡単なことかもしれませんが、ネット検索では事例が出てこなく、手詰まりです。
どなたか方法を教えていただけませんか。

Comment: 「簡単なこと」じゃあないですね。だから「ネット検索では事例が出て」こないんだと思います。まず **Photos Framework** をお調べになってはいかがですか？iPhoneの写真ライブラリにアクセスするためのフレームワークです。それと、Apple直接のドキュメントは、まだObjective-Cベースのものしかない状態なので、Swift限定で検索するのは、効率悪すぎと思います。

Comment: 写真の何をリネームしたいのか(ファイル名をリネームしたいのか写真内にあるexif情報のタイトル名をリネームしたいのか等)を明確にする必要があると思います。ファイル名であれば、どこに格納されている写真なのかも明確化した方がよいと思います。もし写真ライブラリ内のファイル名をリネームしたいのであれば、ライブラリ内部で管理しているファイル名をなぜリネームしたいのかも補足した方が適切な回答を得られやすいと思います。

Comment: TakeOneさんの指摘についてお答えします。リネームしたいのは写真名です。（ファイル名というのでしょうか）　その写真は当方で試作中iPhoneアプリケーションの変数内に格納されています。保存にはcoredataを使用しています。リネームの目的は、書き出したときに管理が楽になるというところです。なぜライブラリを使わないのかというと、念のためオリジナルをバックアップしておきたいからです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 補足ありがとうございます。CoreDataを使用して保存しているということは、イメージデータのバイナリをデータベースレコードに書き込んでいるのだと思います。ということはファイル名のリネームの話ではありません。
あなたがリネームしたいと言っている「写真名」が、具体的にどのような方法(コーディング)で保存したり参照したりしているものか説明しないと誰も答えられないと思います。もしその「写真名」がデータベースレコードのフィールドとして書き込み/参照しているものであれば、データベースレコードのフィールド更新をするにはどうしたらいいかというデータベースアクセス方法の質問になります。雰囲気的には、写真を保存している変数の変数名をリネームするにはどうしたらいいか?という質問にも聞こえますが、いずれにしてもリネームしたいと言っているものにアクセスするための具体的なコードを説明すればはっきりすると思います。

Comment: 返事が遅くなって申し訳ありません。この件は自己解決いたしました。またよろしくお願いします。